BottomNavigationView never fills system navigation buttons when edge to edge
I'm trying to make edge to edge UI with top nav bar, bottom nav bar and drawer.
the BottomNavigationView doesn't want to fill the system navigation buttons. screenshot
i've tried to put the BottomNavigationView alone in LinearLayout, but still the same issue.
neither the color of system navigation buttons changed nor the BottomNavigationView overlapped with system navigation buttons.
i tried to put buttons and image without the BottomNavigationView, both work well and overlapped with system navigation buttons.
but once i add the BottomNavigationView they just disappeared? or have been covered behind the BottomNavigationView, and all became over the system navigation buttons.
i'm using material design 3 so i don't know if the issue from it or not.
i've tried to add fitsSystemWindows to everything, tried true/false, removed from some, add it to some, moved the BottomNavigationView element out side of the drawer, and too many other desperate attempts.
all what i want is just to make it like this screenshot.
xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:fontFamily="@font/helveticarounded"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:fontFamily="@font/helveticarounded"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/AppBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/helveticarounded">
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/Frame_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/helveticarounded"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                android:elevation="8dp">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                    android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_menu_24"
                    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/helveticarounded"
                    app:title="@string/app_name" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/helveticarounded" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer" />



</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

java:
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
       
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


    }


I check the source code of BottomNavigationView.java.
In BottomNavigationView.applyWindowInsets(), engineers avoid the issue of overlapping with the system navigation bar by adding padding to the bottom.
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView.java#L142
The BottomNavigationView component is displayed above the system navigation bar, which seems to be in line with the MaterialUI design requirements.

I think i will try to change the color of system navigation bar to match the BottomNavigationView back color.

even that didn't work, i couldn't get the background color of the BottomNavigationView.

what's the android version of your phone? (Settings -> About phone -> Android version)
I guess your Android version is 15.
In the Android 15，It is deprecated about xxxNavigationBarColor(). After Android 15, it is no longer possible to set the color of the system navigation bar.
Reference: https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/35/changes

When upgrading from Android 14 to Android 15, please refer to the following link for Edge-to-edge behavior. Reference the App targeting Android 15 and the Display content edge-to-edge in your app will help you.

I'm now using android 14, but thank you so much for this information, I will try to avoid changing the color of the navigation bar
